# Guidance in scripts/not really sure what I am looking for

Tags: html, forms, webforms

I am 3 semesters into CS degree, and am looking to do some learning on my own. As a side project I have decided to try and make a script that will every set interval (say 5mins) enter a course # I am trying to get into (which is currently full) into an html text box, and then submit it (by 'pressing' the button on the html website)

I honestly have no clue where to start, and ANY guidance is appreciated with what topics I should begin.

Thanks again, and sorry if this is a 'dumb' question....I searched around and either doing something like this is way over my head or I just haven't hit that lucky query yet.

Comment: look into Autoit, for web task automation

Comment: Thanks a bunch, after a quick glance this looks like it might be just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you like [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), you should probably accept this for answer :)